# Why am I getting random numbers in my result?

Tags: c

I am trying to 4x4 input in an 5x5 array and get the sum of each lines on the fifth lines.
I'm sure if you read my code below, you'll know what I am trying to talk about.
For example if I type in:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

The expected Result should be:

```
1 2 3 4 10
5 6 7 8 26
9 10 11 12 42
13 14 15 16 58
28 32 36 40 136
```

Instead, I am getting a result like:

```
1 2 3 4 10
5 6 7 8 32792
9 10 11 12 42
13 14 15 16 58
28 32 36 40 -501277720
```

I thought about why I get these random values, but couldn't find a solution. Why am I getting these values and what can I do to solve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int gradeArr[5][5];
    int i,j;
    printf("Input grades:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&gradeArr[i][j]);
            gradeArr[i][4] += gradeArr[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", gradeArr[1][4]);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            gradeArr[4][i] += gradeArr[j][i];
        }
        gradeArr[4][4] += gradeArr[4][i];
    }
    printf("Result: \n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",gradeArr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know that `scanf` returns a value - that you should check! (i.e. `if (scanf(....`

Comment: You're adding to array elements that you haven't previously initialized to zero, e.g. `gradeArr[4][4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the array.

Try

```
int gradeArr[5][5] = {0};
```